# Error in Xamarin.Android: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin, emgucv

I have a `Xamarin.Android` app and I want to do some image processing. I installed the EmguCV nuget package, since I have worked with this OpenCV wrapper before on Desktop applications.

Anyhow as soon as I new up an instance of an QRCodeDetector I get the error listed in the title:

```
var qrDetector = new QRCodeDetector();
```

From what I can gather from similar posts, this issue seems to be caused by missing `.dll`s, however since I used nuget to get the library, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: It looks as if Android support is a paid option licence or it at least it was a Emgu.CV v3.

Comment: Further looking around looks as if support of Android as at best been neglected for sometime. Even the latest documentation it has not been updated for many years and the associated forum/group pages have been quiet just as long: https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d5/df8/tutorial_dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Comment: [Emgu CV for Android](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV_for_Android)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a read!

Comment: @RolandDeschain Did you manage to make any progress here?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The project was about QR detection and tracking from the camera stream, I ended up trying Zxing. In the future I probably will go and try the direkt route with android studio and the opencv sdk for android.